# CSS background color for active tab in card header

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Ive searched a few places and received a few responses for this issue yet im still unable to fix it.

I have a darkmode version of my asp.net site and everything works except the active card-header tab. Ive tried a bunch of different CSS to figure it out but i cant get it.

I thought something like this would work

```
.nav-link > .active {
    background-color: var(--bg);
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

or

```
.nav-link:active
```

or

```
.nav-link.active
```

or

```
.card-header.active
```

etc. etc..

None of these options (some are solutions given by Stack overflow members) are getting my background color to follow my darkmode theme.

Here is the code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div class="card login-logout-tab">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Identity/Account/Login">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Sign up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

<script>
    $(function () {
        var current = location.pathname;
        $('.nav-tabs li a').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (current.indexOf($this.attr('href')) !== -1) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

These are the areas that i want to change the background color for:

```
<li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link active" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Sign up</a>
</li>
```

Comment: just use nav-item instead of nav-link (Y)

Comment: That also doesnt work